# Bezier curve : Problem deriving control points from matrix form

Tags: matrix, bezier-curve, java

This is my first post on this website so i have put in a lot of research to get my point across to everyone as clearly as possible.

Based on a question i [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410883/bezier-curve-forcing-a-curve-of-4-points-to-pass-through-control-points-in-3d) on stack overflow i have successfully derived the control points for an bezier curve.Recently i have learned from an [article](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-09/lectures/splines.pdf) that curves can be represented in matrix form as well so as an practise i decided to derive the bezier control points again but from it's matrix form.

If we refer to slide 4 for the basis matrix  and slide 14 from the article for the bezier functions we will find all the parameters needed to construct an bezier curve in the matrix form.

Equation 1

```
[a]=  [2  -2   1   1][f(0)]
[b]=  [-3  3  -2  -1][f(1)]
[c]=  [0   0   1   0][f'(0)]
[d]=  [1   0   0   0][f'(1)]

where for an bezier curve
f(0)=P0
f(1)=P3
f'(0)=T0=3(P1-P0)
f'(1)=T1=3(P3-P2)

and finally a point on the curve is
p=at^3+bt^2+ct+d where t is normalized time ranging from 0-->1
```

Now from my related post i want to derive the control points so i have to work backwards. I want to find at times t1=1/3 and t2=2/3 what should be the new control points such that they pass through the current control points P0 and P1.

This is what i have worked out

```
//We want the bezier curve to pass through p1 and p2. Let us consider only the x axis and equate both sides

p1.x=a*(1/3^3)+b(1/3^2)+c*(1/3)+d    (2)
p2.x=a*(2/3^3)+b(2/3^2)+c*(2/3)+d    (3)

Now writing equation 1 only for x axis we have
[a]=  [2  -2   1   1][P0.x]
[b]=  [-3  3  -2  -1][P3.X]
[c]=  [0   0   1   0][3(P1.x-P0.x)]
[d]=  [1   0   0   0][3(P3.x-P2.x)]

on solving we have our abcd values which are

a=2P0.x-2P3.x+3(P1.x-P0.x)+3(P3.x-P2.x)
b=-3P0.X+3P3.X-6(P1.x-P0.x)-3(P3.x-P2.x)
c=3(P1.x-P0.x)
d=3(P3.x-P2.x)

Upon further simplifying and keeping P1.x and P2.x as the unknowns as those are the new control points we want to find out we have

a= -P0.x+3P1.x-3P2.x+P3.x
b= 3P0.x-6P1.x+3P2.x
c= 3P1.x-3P0.x
d= 3P3.x-3P2.x

Upon substituting the values in equation 2 we have
p1.x=(-P0.x+3P1.x-3P2.x+P3.x)(1/3^3) + (3P0.x-6P1.x+3P2.x)(1/3^2) + (3P1.x-3P0.x)(1/3) + 3P3.x-3P2.x

rearranging all the constants[P0 and P3] to the left hand side we have
p1.x + ((P0.x-P3.x)*(1/3^3)) + (-3P0.x*(1/3^2)) + (3P0.x*1/3) -3P3.x = 3(P1.x-P2.x)(1/3^3)-3(2P1.x-P2.x)(1/3^2) + 3P1.x*1/3 - 3P2.x

We will call the constant on left hand side as c1 for now. Upon furthur rearranging P1 and P2 terms
c1=(3*(1/3^3) - 6*(1/3^2) + 3(1/3))P1.x + (-3*(1/3^3) +3*(1/3^2) -3)P2.x

we will call 1/3 as t1 as we might change this to make the curve look diffrent then we have

c1=(3t1^3-6t1^2+3t1)P1.x + (-3t1^3+3t1^2-3)P2.x

Or
c1=a1P1.x+b1P2.x   (4)

similarly doing the exact same stuff for equation 3 but using p2.x and t2=2/3 we have
c2=a2P1.x+b2P2.x   (5)

 upon writing in matrix form we have

 [c1]=[a1  b1][P1.x]
 [c2]=[a2  b2][P2.x]

  Or
  C=BP BP=C 

  and

  P=inverse(B)C
```

Here is the java pseudo code i have implemented for this. I have used an float array as i want to use bezier curve for any dimension.

```
 public static void bezierAdjust(float[] p0,float[] p1,float[] p2,float[] p3)
 {
  float
  t1=1.0f/3.0f,
  t2=2.0f/3.0f; 
  
  Matrix2f solver=new Matrix2f();
 
  for(int i=0;i<p0.length;i++) //i=0 x axis,i=1 y axis,i=2 z axis
  {
   //solve for t1 and p1
   double
   a1=((3*Math.pow(t1,3))-(6*Math.pow(t1,2))+(3*t1)),
   b1=(-(3*Math.pow(t1,3))+(3*Math.pow(t1,2))-3), 
   c1=p1[i]+((p0[i]-p3[i])*Math.pow(t1,3))+((-3*p0[i])*Math.pow(t1,2))+(3*p0[i]*t1)-(3*p3[i]);
   
   //solve for t2 and p2
   double
   a2=((3*Math.pow(t2,3))-(6*Math.pow(t2,2))+(3*t2)),
   b2=(-(3*Math.pow(t2,3))+(3*Math.pow(t2,2))-3), 
   c2=p2[i]+((p0[i]-p3[i])*Math.pow(t2,3))+((-3*p0[i])*Math.pow(t2,2))+(3*p0[i]*t2)-(3*p3[i]);
  
   solver.load(FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[]{(float)a1,(float)a2,(float)b1,(float)b2})); //load column wise
   solver.invert();
   Vector2f abSolved=Matrix2f.transform(solver,new Vector2f((float)c1,(float)c2),new Vector2f());
   
   p1[i]=abSolved.x;
   p2[i]=abSolved.y;
  }
 }
```

Unfortunatly all that hard work turned my bezier curve from looking like this without any control point modification

[image]

To this.

[image]

I have posted the same question on stackoverflow but i haven't got any answers yet. Can someone guide me as to where i went wrong if it's my code or calculation or both?